# Updating values on frontend but returning NaN

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am trying to automatically update and refresh my item total in my cart page when an item quantity is updated. I keep getting an a return of NaN. I also see a console log of price is undefined, but I don't know how to solved this.

**Script:**

```
  function updateCartItem(cartId, cartItemId, quantityToAdd, csrftoken, price) {
    console.log('price:', price);
    fetch(`/api/carts/${cartId}/items/${cartItemId}/`, {
      method: "PATCH",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        quantity: quantityToAdd,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("Cart successfully updated:", data);
        console.log("CART:", cartId)
        fetch("/cart/")
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((html) => {
            // update the cart items and total price on the page with the new cart data
            const parser = new DOMParser();
            const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
            const itemsContainer = document.getElementById("cart-items");
            const totalContainer = document.getElementById("cart-total");
            if (itemsContainer) {
                itemsContainer.innerHTML = doc.getElementById("cart-items").innerHTML;
            }
            if (totalContainer) {
                totalContainer.textContent = doc.getElementById("cart-total").textContent;
            }
            const itemTotalContainer = document.getElementById(`item-total-${cartItemId}`);
            console.log('itemTotalContainer:', itemTotalContainer);
                    if (itemTotalContainer) {
                        const quantity = parseInt(itemTotalContainer.dataset.quantity);
                        const newQuantity = quantity + quantityToAdd;
                        const newTotal = newQuantity * price;
                        itemTotalContainer.textContent = `£${newTotal.toFixed(2)}`;
                        itemTotalContainer.dataset.quantity = newQuantity;
                    }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    updateItemQuantity(); // update the quantity values on the page after the cart has been updated
    updateCartQuantity(); // update the total cart quantity on the page
    });
}
```

**Html:**

```
<div class="cart--box__item" id="item-total-{{item.id}}" data-quantity="{{ item.quantity }}">£{{item.total}}</div>
```

**EDIT**
**This is how updateCartItem is been called, I hope this can add more context for you.**

```
const cartButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".update-cart");

cartButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const productId = this.dataset.product;
    const action = this.dataset.action;

    if (action === "add") {
      addToCart(productId);
    } else if (action === "remove") {
      removeFromCart(productId);
    }
  });
});

// Grabs users cart id
function addToCart(productId, price) {
  fetch("/get_cart_id/")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      const cartId = data.cart_id;
      const csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");

      fetch(`/api/carts/${cartId}/items/`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          let itemExists = false;
          let cartItemId = null;

          for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].product.id === parseInt(productId)) {
              itemExists = true;
              cartItemId = data[i].id;
              const newQuantity = data[i].quantity + 1;
              // calculate new quantity by adding 1 to existing quantity
              updateCartItem(cartId, cartItemId, newQuantity, csrftoken, price); // pass in new quantity
              break;
            }
          }

          if (!itemExists) {
            createCartItem(cartId, productId, 1, csrftoken);
          }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing how `updateCartitem` is being called. Please include the part where you use the function. Also please specify what specifically is returning `NaN`.

Comment: Your function is called with this parameters `cartId, cartItemId, quantityToAdd, csrftoken, price` console log them using `typeof` for every one.  Getting NaN is usually effect of executing math functions and operators on something that is not a number, and it looks like this might be a case, as only one `quantity` is for sure integer(number), as you parse it that type.

Comment: Try indenting the code more precisely: as far as I can tell `updateItemQuantity();` and `updateCartQuantity()` are being executed in the fulfilled handler of the first `fetch` call, without waiting for the second `fetch("/cart/")` operation to  complete and be processed - which looks suspicious. If the price is logged as  `undefined` it is not being passed correctly. Check that 5 arguments  are actually being passed in the call to  `updateCartItem` and the last one is not `undefined`.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I have added what you requested, going throughs some logs now.

Comment: @Seti Everything is returning perfectly on console.log apart from 'price'. price is returning as undefined.  I also logged right after : itemTotalContainer: <div class=​"cart--box__item" id=​"item-total-61" data-quantity=​"32">​£NaN​</div>​

Comment: If price is undefined, then trying to add/subtract will end up in NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I seem to of fixed my issue.

I needed to add data-price="{{item.product.price}}" to the following line:

```
<div class="cart--box__item" id="item-total-{{item.id}}" data-quantity="{{ item.quantity }}" data-price="{{item.product.price}}">£{{item.total}}</div>
```

I then updated the code in the itemTotalContainer to:

```
if (itemTotalContainer) {
            const quantity = parseInt(quantityToAdd);
            const itemPrice = parseFloat(itemTotalContainer.dataset.price);
            const newTotal = quantity * itemPrice
            console.log("itemTotalContainer:", itemTotalContainer);
            itemTotalContainer.textContent = `£${newTotal.toFixed(2)}`;
            itemTotalContainer.dataset.quantity = quantity;
          }
```